# Setting Azure Ad Api permission for Dynamics CRM Online using Azure Powershell (AZ Module)

Tags: azure, powershell

I have successfully created Azure Powershell using AZ module to register app with Azure AD using app registration. Now as a next step I need to add Dynamics CRM Online API permission to this registered app and grant admin consent to it. Please help how we can do it using AZ module, there are lot of help using old AZURE/AZURERM module but not much help available for AZ.

[Click here to check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6bGH.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure API permissions fro Azure AD application with PowerShell, I suggest you use [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) module. The module is used to manage Azure AD resource

for example

```
Install-Module AzureAD
Import-Module AzureAD

 Connect-AzureAD

 $requiredAccess = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess
 $requiredAccess.ResourceAppId ="00000007-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
 $requiredAccess.ResourceAccess = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]
 $resourceAccess = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess
 $resourceAccess.Type="Scope"
 $resourceAccess.Id="78ce3f0f-a1ce-49c2-8cde-64b5c0896db4"
 $requiredAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($resourceAccess)

 Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId "<object id>" -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredAccess
```